# Angular 6 BehaviorSubject using LocalStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, httpclient, behaviorsubject

I'm having a problem saving data after refreshing a page. I'm using a shared service to pass data between unrelated components. I searched over all Google about LocalStorage and how to use it and I didn't get an answer. there are so many different implements of LocalStorage that I don't know what fits my project.
I have  course-detail component which pass course id to the service, and course-play component which get that id and request http get with this id. every time I refresh course-play page the data disappear. I need help with what to write and where when using LocalStorage to save this data after refresh (and update the id when I'm in a different course).
I'll attach the relevant code:

**course.service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ICourse } from './course';

// Inject Data from Rails app to Angular app
@Injectable()
export class CourseService{

  // JSON url to get data from
  private url = 'http://localhost:3000/courses';
  private courseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/courses.json';

  // Subscribe data
  private courseId = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  public courseId$ = this.courseId.asObservable();

  // here we set/change value of the observable
  setId(courseId) {
    this.courseId.next(courseId)
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Handle Any Kind of Errors
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    // A client-side or network error occured. Handle it accordingly.
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occured:', error.error.message);
    }

    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
    else {
      console.error(
        'Backend returned code ${error.status}, ' +
        'body was ${error.error}');
    }

    // return an Observable with a user-facing error error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happend; please try again later.');
  }

  // Get All Courses from Rails API App
  getCourses(): Observable<ICourse[]> {
  const coursesUrl = `${this.url}` + '.json';

  return this.http.get<ICourse[]>(coursesUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // Get Single Course by id. will 404 if id not found
  getCourse(id: number): Observable<ICourse> {
    const detailUrl = `${this.url}/${id}` + '.json';
    return this.http.get<ICourse>(detailUrl)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }


}
```

**course-detail.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';


// Course-detail decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-detail',
  templateUrl: './course-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-detail.component.sass']
})

export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  course: ICourse;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
  }

  // On start of the life cycle
  ngOnInit() {
    // get the current course id to use it on the html file
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    // set curretn course Id in the service to use it later
    this.courseService.setId(id);
    this.getCourse(id);
    }

    // Get course detail by id
    getCourse(id: number) {
        this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
          course => this.course = course,
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
      }

}
```

**course-play.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';


// Couse-play decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-play-course-play',
  templateUrl: './course-play.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-play.component.sass']
})

export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  course: ICourse;
  courseId: number;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router) {
         courseService.courseId$.subscribe( courseId => {
           this.courseId = courseId;
         })
    }

    // On start of the life cycle
    ngOnInit() {
        // get the current segment id to use it on the html file
        const segment_id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('segment_id');

        console.log(this.courseId);
        this.getCourse(this.courseId);
      }


      // Get course detail by id
      getCourse(id: number) {
          console.log(id);
          this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
            course => this.course = course,
            error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
          );
        }

}
```

Comment: What data is it that you want to store in `localStorage`? Whenever you want to store something, use `localStorage.setItem("Your_key", JSON.stringify(yourValue))`, and when you want to retrieve it, `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Your_key"))`

Comment: I want to save courseId. where to save it? what your_key mean? it's name? and where to use it? in the service or the component that I'm getting from?

Comment: `localStorage` is a key value pair, so we're storing it with the name `your_key`, which means when we want to retrieve it, we must also use `your_key`. You can use any string you like. I would sugges calling `localStorage` from within the service. Save the courseId every time it changes

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have an error in the `setId()` method - it has to have a value of the course ID as an argument and not the subject.

You need to update the local storage right after you invoke `next()` on the subject, and reload the saved data from the storage in the constructor of the service. For example,

```
const COURSES_IN_STORAGE = 'courses_in_storage';

@Injectable()
export class CourseService{
...
  courseIdState: string;

  // This method is invokes by the component  
  setId(courseIdValue: string) {
    this.courseId.next(courseIdValue);
    localStorage.setItem(COURSES_IN_STORAGE, courseIdValue);
  }

 constructor() {
    this.courseIdState = localStorage.getItem(COURSES_IN_STORAGE) || {}; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data into localstorage by this:

localStorage.setItem('variablename', JSON.stringify('data you want to save'));

and to get data back from localstorage by this:

this.anyvariable= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedvariablename'));

that's it about localstorage: